# Possible ways to send huge amount of data to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, transfer, data-transfer

I have a step form in a project that handles a lot of data. To prevent errors during creation, all information is stored client-side, and in the end, is sent to the server.

the information sent to the server looks like this:

```
{
name: "project1",
decription: "lot of text",
schedule:[{weekDay:1, startHour:"09:00", endHour:"15:00"}, ...]
tasks:["task1", "task2"... until 20/30],
files:[{file1}, {file2}, ...],
services:[{
   name: "service1",
   decription: "lot of text",
   schedule:[{weekDay:1, startHour:"09:00", endHour:"15:00"}, ...]
   tasks:["task1", "task2"... until 20/30],
   files:[{file1}, {file2}, ...],
   jobs:[{
       name: "job1",
       decription: "lot of text",
       schedule:[{weekDay:1, startHour:"09:00", endHour:"15:00"}, ...]
       tasks:["task1", "task2"... until 20/30],
        files:[{file1}, {file2}, ...]
       },{
           name: "job2",
      }
   ]
   ...
   },{
      name:"service2",
      ...
   }
}
```

And so on.. 
This is a really reduced example, in a real enviroment there will be 1 project with about 10-15 services, each one with 4-5 jobs.

I have been able to process everything with about 15 items in the last level, and now I´m trying to preprocess data to delete objects not neeeded in the server before send, and with that I expect to be able to send over 50 items in the last level without triggering "max_input_variables exceeded xxx" server side. But still, will be very close to the limit in some cases.

I´m thinking about changing the way I send/receive data, but I´m not sure if my guesses are even correct.

Before some suggest a json request to prevent the input variables error, the request has to bee multipart/form-data to send files.

Said that, my guesses were the following:

- Mount all the data as json in a single variable and keep the files in separated variables ( formData would look like `{project:{hugeJSON}, files:[file1, file2], services:[{files:[...]}, {files:[...]}] }` )
- Send partial data during the form fill to the server and store it somewhere, (a tmp file would be my best bet) and in the last step, send only the main form information.
- Probably a stupid guess, but is there something like sending chunked data? Ideally, I would like to show to the user a loading bar saying "Creating project--> Saving Service nº1 --> Generating Docs for Service 1..." I think that I could achieve this making my server-side script generate a chunked reponse, but not sure about that.

Well, any help that could show me the correct way would be really appreciated.

Tank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are finished filling your object, you should stringify it and send it to the server as a post parameter.

Once you receive it serverside, you can parse JSON and continue working.